# Optimized way to check for equality between value of Objects inside a List

Tags: java, performance, iteration, java-7, nested-loops

I have two lists :
A : List<MyCustomObject>
B. List<MyCustomObject>

**MyCustomObject** has various fields. For instance a field **id**

In my program, I need to check if same **id** exists in both lists. So currently I am doing nested iterations :

```
for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++) {

   MyCustomObject obj = a.get(i);

   for(int j=0;j<b.size();j++) {

    if( obj.getId().equals(b.get(j).getId()) {

        //do something
        break;
       }
   }
 }
```

As I frequently need to do this operation, it looks me unoptimized as I am frequently iterating over long lists.

How can I optimize this operation ?

Comment: Could you not hold your objects in a `Map` with `id` as the key?

Comment: It can't be done less than `O(n^2)`. So I think it is pretty much ok. You can use some built-in function but still would be same. Though this type of question need to be asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @tintinmj sure it can be done in less than `O(n^2)`!  An `O(n)` insertion of the first lists IDs into a `HashSet` followed by an `m * O(1)` search of each ID from the second list gives what is in effect still a linear time search.

Comment: @Novice You may sort (by id) these two lists before processing, so you'd not need to start with 0 in the 2nd loop every time.

Comment: @beny23 a `HashSet` would be more ideal - there's no need for a "value" field.

Comment: [Guava's `MultiMap`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) could also serve as place to keep multiple things grouped with one key together.

Comment: @Alnitak, I mean if instead of having two lists in the first place, maps were used.  If you only had sets of ids, where would you hold the MyCustomObjects (the sample code explicitly compares the id fields, so one cannot assume that `MyCustomObject` has the `.equals` and `.hashCode` overwritten).

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying, but a list and a map are not the same thing.  A list can have repeated elements, a map cannot have repeated keys.  The OP is not specific on whether this is an issue or not.

Comment: Duplicate is not issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a list you could use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html), for example a HashMap - assuming your id is an int, it could look like:

```
Map<Integer, MyCustomObject> objects = new HashMap<>();
//populate
objects.put(someCustomObject.getId(), someCustomObject);
//find an id:
CustomObject obj = objects.get(someId);
```

note: that assumes that the ids are unique.

Answer (score 1):

A linear-time algorithm is to hash the ID values in the first list against a Boolean.  Then you travel on the second list to look up the ID values, and if the hash already contains a key of that ID, the ID is shared between the two lists.

You can also improve over the runtime of O(n^2) by sorting the lists by id, which is an O(n log n) operation, and traveling through the lists linearly to see if any of the values are shared.  If you want to keep the order of the lists, you could create another, sorted copy of the lists but that would add memory space.

What you've got, I believe, is as good as you can do without changing the order of the list elements or creating a new data structure.  I don't know your requirements, though.